# How to compile `.framework` file?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, theta360

I searched through existing **Stackoverflow** questions related to this problem but didn't find any help to solve it.

So here's the problem:

I am trying to integrate `.framework` file into the project but it's giving me an error saying that module compiles with 4.0.3 can't be imported by swift 5.0 compiler.

I wanted to know how to compile that`.framework` file? so that it will become compilable to swift 5.0

Please help if you come across such a problem.

> Note: `.framework` file is created by a third-party developer

Comment: Ask Third-party Developer to update existing .framework to Swift 5.0 version

Comment: @UmaMadhavi yeah that is there. But is there any other way I can solve it??

Comment: your versions do not match, looks like they need to, so you need an updated version of the framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the framework you're trying to integrate is binary only, then your best option is to check with the 3rd party developer regarding their support for Swift 5.0.

In case there are sources available, you can try checking if there is any work being done in their repository (usually a separate branch), or you can try forking the sources yourself.

Note that with the source option, you'll have access to possibly unstable and untested code, and depending on the experience I'd be very careful in this case.